# Create an array of a single property extracted from an array of objects

Tags: javascript, arrays, object, push

I'm trying to push a property of each object from an array of objects onto another array.

Here is the code that I have:

```
for (var i = 0; i < arr2.length; i++) {
  var dates = [];
  dates.push(arr2[i].date);
}
console.log(dates);
```

This is the data:

```
var arr2 = [{"id":"1","exchange_symbol":"TSE","currency":"JPY","stock_id":"1","stock_name":"KYOKUYO CO.,LTD.","stock_symbol":"1301.T","date":"2006-12-29","time":"15:00:00.000000","close":"2388.023438000000000000","volume":"23700.000000000000000000","active":"1","exchange_id":"0"},{"id":"2","exchange_symbol":"TSE","currency":"JPY","stock_id":"1","stock_name":"KYOKUYO CO.,LTD.","stock_symbol":"1301.T","date":"2007-01-04","time":"15:00:00.000000","close":"2416.452637000000000000","volume":"16500.000000000000000000","active":"1","exchange_id":"0"},{"id":"3","exchange_symbol":"TSE","currency":"JPY","stock_id":"1","stock_name":"KYOKUYO CO.,LTD.","stock_symbol":"1301.T","date":"2007-01-05","time":"15:00:00.000000","close":"2369.071045000000000000","volume":"45400.000000000000000000","active":"1","exchange_id":"0"},{"id":"4","exchange_symbol":"TSE","currency":"JPY","stock_id":"1","stock_name":"KYOKUYO CO.,LTD.","stock_symbol":"1301.T","date":"2007-01-09","time":"15:00:00.000000","close":"2388.023438000000000000","volume":"28800.000000000000000000","active":"1","exchange_id":"0"}];
```

I was looking forward to my `console.log(dates)` to look something like this:

```
"2006-12-29"
"2007-01-04"
"2007-01-05"
"2007-01-09"
```

Yet I get this:

```
[Object {"id":"4","exchange_symbol":"TSE","currency":"JPY","stock_id":"1","stock_name":"KYOKUYO CO.,LTD.","stock_symbol":"1301.T","date":"2007-01-09","time":"15:00:00.000000","close":"2388.023438000000000000","volume":"28800.000000000000000000","active":"1","exchange_id":"0"}];
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your code has two issues:

1) the result array is re-initialized inside each iteration of your loop

2) you need to access the `.date` property of your source object specifically (this was amended in an edit)

```
var dates = [];

for (var i = 0; i < arr2.length; i++) {
  dates.push(arr2[i].date);
}

console.log(dates);
```

You can also use [`Array#map`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map) to apply a function to every element in an array and return a new one:

```
const dates = arr2.map(e => e.date);
console.log(dates);
```

Comment: Yes sorry typo, I had .date in my original code. But now I get the following: [undefined, undefined, undefined, undefined]

Comment: That's not my output. Are you including all of your code? Check this repl: https://repl.it/repls/BlankAgedProspect

Comment: Indeed. Thanks.